# In JointJS, how an element accesses position, inPorts, outPorts?

Tags: javascript, position, jointjs

I am using jointJS for my academic project, I have such a question, How an element accesses position, inPorts, outPorts?
For example, we create an element like this,

```
var m1 = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
size: { width: 90, height: 90 },
inPorts: ['in1','in2'],
outPorts: ['out'],
attrs: {
    '.label': { text: 'Model', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2 },
    rect: { fill: '#2ECC71' },
    '.inPorts circle': { fill: '#16A085' },
    '.outPorts circle': { fill: '#E74C3C' }
}
});
graph.addCell(m1);
```

I want to get `position` and `inPorts` from `m1`, I have tried `m1( 'position' )` 
and `m1.position()`
, but it didn't work.

Can someone solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `m1.get('position')` and `m1.get('inPorts')`. You could also use `m1.prop('position')` and `m1.prop('inPorts')`. The difference is that `get(property)` is only for accessing flat properties while `prop(path)` is able to get nested properties as well (e.g. `m1.prop('attrs/rect/fill')`.